# Asp.net MVC , Entity Framework how to add + 1 to the data in string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

Goodmorning everyone, I was just wondering how to add + 1 to the data you enter? using string?

```
    public string QueueNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", Name ?? "?", ServiceLetter);
        }
        set { }
    }
```

This is my sample format, I just wanna display like

- JaneDoeA001
- JackDoeA002

Basically Adding + 1 for every input

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to go on but if you have a dataset with identity column (auto-increment in database). You can append that ID to your format.